# Best secure way to store JWT tokens instead of storing in local/session storage?

Tags: c#, authentication, jwt, .net-6.0

We are using JWT token authentication mechanism, we have UI, that has a login page, and once the user logs in, the user token is stored in local storage, however, local/session storage and even cookies are not a safe place to store token as they are prone to CSS attacks, so, what would be the best way to store tokens.

Also, I received one question from a lead, if the token is stolen from my machine, is it possible to restrict or identify it, I said once stolen it's gone until the token expires, this is true, right?

```
[Route("api/auth")]
[ApiController]
public class AuthController : ControllerBase
{
    // GET api/values
    [HttpPost, Route("login")]
    public IActionResult Login([FromBody]LoginModel user)
    {
        // ... other code is omitted for the brevity
        return Ok(new { Token = tokenString });
    }
}

login(form: NgForm) {
    // ... other code is omitted for the brevity
    localStorage.setItem("jwt", token);
    // ... other code is omitted for the brevity
    
}
```

Comment: You don't have access to anything else besides local/session storage, where do you want to put it? JWTs in local storage are fine but the JWT should have few permissions and last as little as possible (1 hour is a good default). Add a longer refresh token stored in session storage and you should be good

Comment: _"Best...way..."_ might be _subject to opinion_ and if so is sadly off-topic for SO. [ask].  Consider re-phrasing your question to be [constructive subjective](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto What do you mean by few permissions, some of the articles say have a cookie with some anti forgery prevention... not sure what it means however I'm looking for expert help.

Comment: @MickyD I feel the question title is appropriate because local/session is good and the most preferred way however I'm looking for better than it, so, "BEST" suites over here.

Comment: Not a problem good sir.